# Voltage in a lossless transmission line

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electric-circuits, voltage

I have a question where I'm deriving expressions for different variables within a lossless transmission line. Here's the question as posed:

*Consider a lossless transmission line of characteristic impedance $R_0$. A time-harmonic voltage source of amplitude, $V_g$ and an internal impedance, $R_g = R_0$ is connected to the input terminals of the line, which is terminated with a load impedance $Z_L=R_L + jX_L$. Let $P_{inc}$ be the average incident power associated with the wave travelling in the $+z$ direction.*

*(a) Find the expression for $P_{inc}$ in terms of $V_g$ and $R_0$*

*(b) Find the expression for the average power, $P_L$ delivered to the load in terms of $V_g$ and the reflection coefficient, $Γ$.*

*(c) Express the ratio $P_L/P_{inc}$ in terms of the standing wave ratio, $S$.*

Now, given the correct equations, I have no doubt I could derive this, but I feel as though I'm getting stuck on a real basic point.

Consider a voltage $V_g$. Within a lossless transmission line, this time-harmonic voltage can be represented by:

$V_g = V_0^{+}e^{-\gamma z} +V_0^{-}e^{\gamma z}$

And the time harmonic current, $I_g$ can be expressed in a very similar way (exchanging V's for I's). **My question is**: When we wish to consider $P_{inc}$, since it is only concerned with the wave travelling in the $+z$ direction, do we need the second term of the above expression? My thoughts are that, because the load isn't matched with the line impedance, there will be a reflection of both voltage and current within the line, and hence at any given point, the voltage will in fact be the above sum. Is this a correct assumption?

Additionally, is my assumption about the general form of the current (taking the same form as the above equation) correct? And when I go to derive an expression for the power, can I simply use $P=VI$?

They seem like all easy questions, but I hate to get things wrong! Help would be much appreciated :)